# Loading screen when PHP queries going on

Tags: javascript, php, asynchronous, loading

I'm trying to make a loading screen for my webapp. I'm using PHP backend and calling a DB query. The fact is, that I expect it to take up to 5 seconds (which is fine). But I'd like to show a loading screen in the meantime and I've found myself somehow struggling with it.

I 100% knew this wouldn't work, but just for illustration of what I need to achieve, I tried this:

```
<div id='loading'>i am loading</div>
<?php
$result = $db->query("some sql here");
if ($result)
    echo "<script>document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';</script>";
?>
```

Although this piece of code is obviously wrong, I hope it is clear from it what I need. NOTE: I cannot really afford redirecting to another page for the loading screen (I saw this as one of the options), unless it is the only possible solution like this. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: You don't do this in PHP. You do it in JavaScript. Display the loading screen before sending the AJAX request, remove it when the response is received.

Comment: You would have to use ajax for this functionality

Comment: If you're just doing normal form submission, all you have to do is show the loading screen when you submit the form. When the response is received the page will reload, which will remove the loading screen automatically.

Comment: You don't have PHP load the Javascript, you have Javascript invoke the PHP via AJAX/XHR. [or what Barmar just said]

Comment: The reason it doesn't work in PHP is because the browser doesn't receive anything until the PHP script is done. So by that time the long query is done. It doesn't process the outpout from PHP incrementally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XMLHttpRequest(), I won't be writing the HTML for this answer.

```
<script>
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.open('POST', 'url_here', true)
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        if (this.responseText == 'success') {
            //JS Logic For Removing Loading Screen Here
        } else if (this.responseText == 'failed') {
            //Error Handling Here
        }
    }
}

xhttp.send('data='+JSON.stringify(data_here));
```

Then in PHP

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$data = json_decode($data);

**DB LOGIC HERE*

if ($result) {
    echo 'success'
} else {
    echo 'failed'
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's the 21st century, examples should recommend `fetch()`, which is much easier to use than XMLHttpRequest.